# How to refer to the last print out Object in JavaScript console of Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: javascript, console

Is there a way to refer to the last object just printed out in the JavaScript console of your favorite browser?

For example there is in your code somewhere a console.log(myObject) at the end of the JavaScript function. Is it possible to than refer in the console to this printed out myObject to do some tests in the console based on this object?

Practical example ...

Code in JavaScript File:

```
console.log("Test");
```

Which prints `Test`

Now I would like to do something like e.g. `console.last().substring(0,2)` which should print `Te`.

Comment: Do you need this in the console input, or from the javascript `console` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible with [the standard `console` API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) However, you could write your own wrapper around `console.log()` which provides this:

```
var _log = console.log;
console.log = function () {
    // turn arguments into an array and store it
    this._last = [].slice.call(arguments);

    // call the original function
    _log.apply(console, arguments);
};

console.last = function() {
    return this._last;
};
```

Note that this implementation of `console.last()` will always return an array, since `console.log()` accepts an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
> console.log('foo', 3, true)
  foo 3 true
> console.last()
  ["foo", 3, true]
```

Comment: Work like a treat! Looks like a nice addition to the console API. Does somebody now where to make this happen?

Comment: @loomi "where to make this happen" as in, you want to add it to the standard console API, without having to shim it yourself? Good luck.

Comment: @MattBall Yes as, where could we put this on an feature request list? I am aware that it now will be done in the next week ...

Comment: The `console` API is non-standard.

Comment: @loomi: I don't think it's a useful addition to the console api, I can't think of any use case where this would be helpful. Also, logging should be a stateless functionality, I don't see a reason to change that - and your `console.last()` would be quite unpredictable. Making logged objects (maybe from a private scope?) available to the public could also be a huge security threat. If you want to try nonetheless, file an issue in your favourite browser's bug tracker.

Comment: @Bergi: It would not make any sense in the scope of the delivered code. But for development it would be, at least for me, really helpful to test/prepare some functionality on a data object. So best it should only be available on in the scope of the console. Or do you know any other technique to test ad-hoc stuff on a object logged to the console without the need for a file write?